# KeyError in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

in the below code  my problem is  , when  word (which s given by user) is searched   when is not  in the my table column,  pop up message appears  and says user doesn't exist , but my if searched is not working, does any body have an idea where i'm doing it wrong, please let me know , i'm working in django, pandas

```
def products(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

    df = pd.read_csv("media_cdn/media/user_change_history.csv",header=None)

    searched = request.POST\['searched'\]

    context = {}

    if  searched in  df.index:

        data = df.loc\[df\[0\] == searched\]

        \#if data in df.index:

        data = data.transpose()

        data = data.to_html(classes='table-wrapper')

        context = {'d': data}

     else:

        messages.info(request, 'Username  is incorrect')

        return render(request, 'blog/products.html', context)

else:

    return render(request, 'blog/products.html')
```

in the above code  my problem is  , when  word (should represent a cell in user ID column) (which s given by user) is searched   when is not  in the my table column,  pop up message appears  and says user doesn't exist , but my if searched is not working, does any body have an idea where i'm doing it wrong, please let me know , i'm working in Django, pandas